# Inputing dates in vector on R

Tags: r, date, cbind

When I input dates on R using the code

```
day1<- as.Date("1999-03-12")
dates<-as.Date(day1+interval)
```

these codes output a list of dates, however when I use the code

```
cbind(x, dates)
```

The dates don't appear as dates, does anyone know how I can put this right so it they appear in the format of a date when transformed into a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cbind()` creates a `matrix`. Matrices in R are constrained to have the same class in all columns, so `dates` is converted into whatever class (character, numeric) `x` is.

Use `data.frame(x=x,dates=dates)` instead.